# Angular - bootstrap modal data not updating

Tags: javascript, angular, ng-bootstrap

In my Angular component, I have a radio group input within bootstrap modal. Upon changing radio button selection, I need to update a variable `selectedSortOption` with latest selected radio value.

Everything works fine. When I change radio selection in `console` I get appropriate value for `selected emit`. Again when I click button in `console` I don't get updated value for `selected`. After every button click in `console` it is always `value1`.

Here is my code.

`*.component.ts` code -

```
@ViewChild('sort') sort: TemplateRef<any>;    
selectedSortOption: string;

// SORT BY
sortList = [
    { text: 'Text 1', value: 'value1' },
    { text: 'Text 2', value: 'value2' }
];

modalRef: BsModalRef;

config = {
    animated: false,
    backdrop: true,
    ignoreBackdropClick: false
};

constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private modalService: BsModalService) {
    this.selectedSortOption = 'value1';
}

triggerMobileCategorySort() {
    console.log('selected', this.selectedSortOption);
    this.modalRef = this.modalService.show(this.sort, this.config);
}

sortChanges(eventData) {
    this.selectedSortOption = eventData;
    console.log('selected emit', this.selectedSortOption);
    this.triggerSortValue.emit(eventData);
    this.modalRef.hide();
}
```

`*.component.html` code -

```
<button (click)="triggerMobileCategorySort()">Select</button>
<ng-template #sort>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <ul>
      <li *ngFor="let a of sortList">
        <input
        type="radio"
        name="radiogroup"
        [value]="a.value"
        (change)="sortChanges(a.value)"
        [checked]="a.value == selectedSortOption">
        {{a.text}}
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</ng-template>
```

For sure, I am missing something.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: That's weird, just tried out the code you've provided (removing the `this.triggerSortValue.emit(eventData);` because the EventEmitter is not declared) and it's working as expected, the issue is probably somewhere else in your code.
What are you doing in the parent component with the emitted value?

Comment: Actually, it sends back the data to parent component. I need to send a HTTP request with emitted data from parent component.